# I'm getting a TypeError in my code: unsupported operand type(s) for ^: 'bytes' and 'bytes'

Tags: python, cryptography, byte, typeerror

I'm new to python3, I'm getting the following error when trying to print the first_block value below.

```
 File "cbcmodechal10.py", line 18, in main
    first_block = iv ^ plaintext[0]
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for ^: 'bytes' and 'bytes'
```

Can please someone also explain why this happens, although both the variables are in bytes, why this operation is not successful?

I know that there is some problem with utf-8 encoding but couldn't figure out what?

```
#!/bin/bash/python3
import urllib.request
import base64
from Crypto.Cipher import AES

def main():
    file = urllib.request.urlopen('https://cryptopals.com/static/challenge-data/10.txt')
    ciphertext = file.read().decode('utf-8')
    cipher = base64.b64decode(ciphertext)
    key = bytes('YELLOW SUBMARINE', 'utf-8')
    iv  = bytes('\x00' * 16, 'utf-8')
    blocksize = 16
    chunks = [cipher[i:i+blocksize] for i in range(0, len(cipher), blocksize)]
    #print(chunks[0])
    cipher1 = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_ECB)
    blocks = int(len(cipher) / blocksize)
    plaintext = [cipher1.decrypt(chunks[j]) for j in range(0, blocks)]
    first_block = iv ^ plaintext[0]
    print(first_block)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

expected output: b"I'm back and I'm"

Comment: you can use it with single bytes - like `iv[0] ^ key[0]`. For more bytes you have to use `for`-loop

Comment: if used iv[0], then that will become an int

Comment: you can convert back `bytes( [ iv[0] ] )`

Comment: It sounds like you want `a^b == bytes(map(operator.xor, a, b))`, but it's not.

Comment: I'm just trying to xor(^) the iv with the first block of plaintext and both of them are utf-8 encoded. Can't really figure out the problem

Comment: I'm just trying to implement the CBC mode with AES ECB mode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I said you have to do it with single bytes

```
first_block = bytes([x^y for x, y in zip(iv, plaintext[0])])
```

This gives me

```
b"I'm back and I'm"
```

---

**EDIT:** as @chepner suggested this also works:

```
first_block = bytes(map(operator.xor, iv, plaintext[0]))
```